# Visual Studio 2017 C# launching powershell script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

Hope this is the right place to ask new to this site :)

I created a GUI in visual studio for new user creation. Part of the code then calls a Powershell script I have been using for user creation.

So the GUI all works I can add the users to a CSV file it creates and then launches the Powershell script.

The problem I get is that part of the Powershell script loads the exchange 2007 snapin. For some reason when running the script via the GUI I have created it always comes up with an error saying it is unable to find the plugin.

So basically the code for launching the Powershell is as follows. Now I am not a coder at all so I could be going about it the wrong way and it might be a bit of a mess hehe :)

```
Process p = new Process();

p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; (false for testing)
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false; //(false for testing)
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; //(false for testing)
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false; //(false for testing)
p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "This points to a file on a network share" @"\\server\folder\file";

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

The above happens after a button click and will be outputting to a text box within the GUI once I have it all working. But for now i have that side of things disabled so i can see the errors in Powershell.

So the error message in Powershell is as follows

> 'Microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.admin' is not installed on this computer

But again if I run the script manually without the GUI it works fine. Its like the GUI is launching it in a closed environment that has no access to the computer its running on. I am prob missing something simple as I really have no idea about creating c# apps.

Comment: The Powershell script was located on a network share so i tried moving it to the local computer as a test but getting the same issue so it does seem like the little GUI program I made is running in its own instance and does not have access to the local users registry settings that would allow it to load the exchange snapin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I have solved the problem.

I should have explained better on what I was doing to launch the Powershell script. Basically I was using the above code to launch a .bat file and doing it that way for whatever reason when that bat file ran it would not work and I would get the above error.

So I used a little program to convert the bat file into an exe and set it to always run as admin. This resolved the issue and now the script runs correctly.

Not sure why but launch the bat file it did not have access to the local user profile so could not load the Powershell exchange snap-in as the details for that are stored in the local users registry.

So the solution was to just change the bat file that my GUI launched for the Powershell script to an EXE file. Not sure why this is but it works :)

Thanks
Michael Smith